# AWS Cloudfront cache MISS with AWSALB cookie

Tags: caching, cookies, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, aws-alb

I have a wordpress website with a setup on EC2, ALB, Cloudfront and varnish. On chrome dev toolbar, I got a problem that cloudfront cache always MISS for document/html type but HIT for the static files like js, css, png, etc. I found on the response header (for document type only) there is a cookie (I believe) from ALB like this :

```
set-cookie: AWSALB=U5AWJwh/v3MaAYRDCdFicDCuiWi9Fy14fiegh0DG2UwTIq5zToBRCrpUO7nqqj2mI5XRcbu9pINYxv0XhmjVC5T2swGCP8RzeAJLrOwy3NLPRB/nJSJD/ng5Iy/0; Expires=Thu, 12 Dec 2019 03:50:07 GMT; Path=/
```

I tried to solve this on the cloudfront cache behaviour setting, then I set :

```
Whitelist Cookies:  AWSALB=*
```

After waiting a few minutes to let the cloudfront cache refreshed, I tried to load the website but I still got a response 'MISS' for x-cache. How to solve this problem. 
Here is the response and request header for the MISS cache:

```
General:
Request URL: https://yyy.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: zzz:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Header:
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 0
cache-control: max-age=3299, public
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 39955
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 05 Dec 2019 01:21:07 GMT
etag: "92d49bdbffc17d570120a667c34465a6"
expires: Thu, 05 Dec 2019 02:16:06 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 05 Dec 2019 01:16:06 GMT
link: <https://yyy.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
link: <https://yyy.com/>; rel=shortlink
pragma: public
server: nginx/1.16.1
set-cookie: AWSALB=7zzIXUQ/O9X6+vce8GWOs1x1ES9/nr7r5/Hc06xmWL5GDMVLeaUJututZeBJf7TVIHdbXmOZgAhvYtkQva9y/bFPi2EPdn3j5MqqbSOiPs+qS+9adILQ95csWH+/; Expires=Thu, 12 Dec 2019 01:21:07 GMT; Path=/
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 f92e2b771ebc524db2f478f72162e565.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: EmCMRJ9cQ6zs0N4tvHAEOZxC1l6vYMIqBTA6hTVlqsxuKj275VRNLQ==
x-amz-cf-pop: SIN5-C1
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
x-varnish: 339894892

Request Header:
:authority: yyy.com
:method: GET
:path: /
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
```

and here is the response and request header for the HIT cache:

```
General:
Request URL: https://yyy.com/wp-content/cache/minify/db66e.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: zzz:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Header:
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 630787
cache-control: max-age=31536000, public
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 100500
content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 27 Nov 2019 18:08:00 GMT
etag: "pub1574872585;gz"
expires: Thu, 26 Nov 2020 18:07:58 GMT
last-modified: Wed, 27 Nov 2019 16:36:25 GMT
pragma: public
server: nginx/1.16.1
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 f92e2b771ebc524db2f478f72162e565.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: -8otMvG_QhBrVBVH8HD0AuzsTwny_o7QkDuQnZnHHqcmqriLuAw_Lw==
x-amz-cf-pop: SIN5-C1
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
x-varnish: 1158322228

Request Header:
:authority: yyy.com
:method: GET
:path: /wp-content/cache/minify/db66e.css
:scheme: https
accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: AWSALB=7zzIXUQ/O9X6+vce8GWOs1x1ES9/nr7r5/Hc06xmWL5GDMVLeaUJututZeBJf7TVIHdbXmOZgAhvYtkQva9y/bFPi2EPdn3j5MqqbSOiPs+qS+9adILQ95csWH+/
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://yyy.com/
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
```

Thanks.

Comment: I mean : Whitelist Cookies:  AWSALB

Comment: ALB cookies changes with every request, ALB adds set-cookies new one everytime so the cookie value changes and cloudfront has to pass it to Origin if Forward all cookies or ALBcookie has been whitelisted, you can see from browser, the cookies values are changing for all the request.

Comment: @JamesDean, I also notice the changes of ALB cookie value. I put the cookie on whitelist cookies and even set All for Forward Cookies value. But the cache still MISS for html content-type. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I also use W3 total cache and redis for the website

Comment: Whitelisting cookies is exactly the wrong thing to do.  This will ensure that you have almost 100% cache misses.  We need a better perspective on how you've configured CloudFront.  For example, is `/` handled by a different cache behavior/path pattern than `....css`?

Comment: @JamesDean , could you explain why ALB cookies constantly change between requests?I would expect them to remain the same , between requests if one use stickiness on targets